# Are centimeters on websites always the same for everyone?

Tags: html, css, pixel

I wanted to ask if centimeters on websites are always the same for everyone. I read somewhere that pixels are getting displayed different based on your current hardware. If I have an A4 page for instance on my website, and I want users to print it out, will every user with different hardware specs get the very same results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to print text you should use "em, cm, mm, in, pt, pc, %" .
These units come from typographia, they have absolute measures.

On the other hand "px" doesn't act like a constant but depends on hardware, you can learn more at : https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/units.en.html .

Comment: but if @JamieC for example says that 1cm == 37.8px and px doesn't act like a constant.. aren't cm constants either then?

Comment: Well in the source @JamieC linked, there is : "The “px” unit in CSS doesn't really have anything to do with screen pixels, despite the poorly chosen name."
So you have to think in term of CSS pixels and not the real screen pixel which is equals at 1/37.8 cm

Comment: @FooBar I think for a print stylesheet, you're ok with cm units. cm for displays are based on the px unit, but inprint, there's not display to base the pixels on.

Answer (score 1):

They are **not** the same for everyone. How it will appear on the screen depends on the [Dots per inch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dots_per_inch) of the display and the user's settings.

If you want to make sure that the print will look *exactly* the same for everyone, you'll have to use a PDF with embedded fonts. Even then, differences can occur (different printers print differently and there are many different PDF viewers).

Comment: So what is the point of having centimeters as a unit then?? It really tilts me that there is a unit that is not precise at all

Comment: Well, it is for printing - but depending on the user's browser and settings the results can still vary.

Answer (score 1):

> 1cm == 37.8px

https://css-tricks.com/the-lengths-of-css/

Pixels also aren't an actual screen pixel.

http://inamidst.com/stuff/notes/csspx